# Sync two SP calendars

Tags: development, my-site, web, sharepoint-calendar, sync

My criteria is as follow:

1. If I add an event in Calendar A , then I want the same event to be added in a different calendar B with some condition. So that I don't have to pick a specific item from that Calendar A and then add it manually in my calendar B.

It should automatically add an event in calendar B once entered in A, but Columns are different in both the Calendars so I want to map only the ones matching in both the Calendars.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to use the function calendar overlay. On Calendar A you can overlay Calendar B and on Calendar B you can overlay calendar A.
Once this have been set up you will find the entries of both calendar in Calendar A and B.

How this works an can be set up can be found in the SharePoint help:
[Overlay a SharePoint calendar on another SharePoint calendar](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-foundation-help/overlay-a-sharepoint-calendar-with-a-calendar-from-exchange-or-sharepoint-HA101777171.aspx#_Toc342550087)

The calendar entries also have different colors then.

Answer (score 0):

The following code for example will loop thru my Calendar list and delete the event with a specified ID, but you can put code in the inner code block which will take the values and write to different calendar.

```
        var myWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
        var listItems = myWeb.Lists["Leave Calendar"].Items;
        var itemCount = listItems.Count;
        for (var k = 0; k < itemCount; k++)
        {
            var item = listItems[k];
            if (requestId == Convert.ToInt32(item["RequestID"]))
            {
                listItems.Delete(k);
                break;
            }
        }
```

And in the following code snippet is how I save items to a calendar

```
protected void WriteToCalendar(string title, string location, DateTime startdate, DateTime enddate, string description, string category, bool alldayevent, string requestid)
    {
        var myWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
        var calendarList = myWeb.Lists["Leave Calendar"];
        var calendarListItem = calendarList.Items.Add();
        calendarListItem["Title"] = title;
        calendarListItem["Location"] = location;
        calendarListItem["Start Time"] = startdate;
        calendarListItem["End Time"] = enddate;
        calendarListItem["Description"] = description;
        calendarListItem["Category"] = category;
        calendarListItem["All Day Event"] = alldayevent;
        calendarListItem["RequestID"] = requestid;
        calendarListItem["Approval Status"] = "Pending";
        calendarListItem["Employee Name"] = title;
        myWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        calendarListItem.Update();
        myWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    }
```

Comment: I dont know where to apply this code as I am not a sharepoint developer and I just want to maintain calendar entries , i.e. one event added incalendar should automatically populate in Calendar B

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Workflow in SharePoint Designer would be the easiest way to handle this, especially with evaluating your conditions and mapping differing columns up.

Comment: So is there a particular link which I can refer to as I am new to sharepoint and dont know much about Sharepoint Designer

Comment: Here's several that should get you started.  http://blogs.salmanghani.info/create-item-workflow-sharepoint-designer-2010/

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/workflow-example-create-a-task-from-a-discussion-item-HA010182910.aspx#BM2

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/workflow-actions-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-a-quick-reference-guide-HA010376961.aspx?CTT=1#_Toc260924448